# X509Certificate file check

Tags: java, x509certificate

I have signed file and I have X509Certificate instance, how to check this file valid according this certificate? Program is written on Java.

Comment: does the cert have a password?

Comment: cert doesnt have a password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example. you can change it from verifiying a message, to verifying a File :
http://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleSMIMEverify.html